# Can C++20's 'operator==(const T&) = default' be mimiqued in C++17?

Tags: c++, boost, c++17, comparator

In C++ 20 we are able let the compiler automatically generate the implementation for `operator==` for us like this (and all the other [default comparasions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_comparisons) too, but I'm just interested in `operator==` here):

```cpp
#include <compare>
struct Point {
  int x;
  int y;
  bool operator==(const Point&) const = default;
};
```

Is there a way to archieve the same (automatically generate `operator==`) but in C++17?

Since libraries are an okay solution I had a look at [boost/operators](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/utility/doc/html/utility/utilities/operators.html). Would the following be the equivalent as the above?

```cpp
#include <boost/operators.hpp>
struct Point : boost<equality_comparable<Point, Point>> {
  int x;
  int y;
  bool operator==(const Point&) const; // will this get auto-generated too and do the same as above?
};
```

Comment: The *syntax* `= default` for operators is C++20's addition. So no.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica the [...] = default was a copy-paste mistake. Sorry. It was meant to be without it like in the example in the boost docs.

Comment: If I'm reading the manual correctly, they generate operators based on existing operators. No magical member detection.

Comment: To auto generate stuff, you'd need reflection, which doesn't exist. But if you're fine with boost describe, there's probably a solution.

Comment: @PasserBy Probably true. [refl-cpp](https://github.com/veselink1/refl-cpp) is a C++17 library that could do that, but it would come at the cost of quite some code overhead which includes macros.

Comment: You could probably fork a compiler and back port the change to be c++17 enabled.

Comment: @sehe I think you greatly over estimate the difficulty level in what i proposed. The only thing stopping the change from being in C++17 is the *standard*, not the compiler. The compiler is _already_ 100% capable of doing exactly what is required. Somewhere in the code is an `#ifdef` that conditionally turns on or off the code based on if you pass `-stdc++17` or `-stdc++20`.

Comment: Well, @Taekahn that makes your solution a false suggestion: "Just use a C++20 compiler (and make it lie about the language level)". That's like saying "It's easy when you already have a real nuclear power plant that was completely built out of cake". You know, not a useful suggestion.

Comment: You don't have to assume malice. I'm trying to understand your point. If you're really suggesting random person X on stackoverflow "easily" beackporting a c++20 to a c++17 compiler *and using that custom toolchain for their projects*, I'm happy to see you do it as an example.

Comment: @sehe i'd gladly do it, given sufficient motivation. But seeing as how i'm not the one that needs the feature, and i don't see anyone clamoring to pay me to do it....

Comment: That suggests that it is obviously more work than the already stated answer.

Comment: That would be a perfectly reasonable reply, if i hadn't have made the suggestion 3 hours before the answer existed. I never stated its less work that the answer you provided, and had your answer existed, i never would have made the comment. And since this isn't reddit, this is the last comment i'm making on the topic. It adds nothing of value to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only for aggregates (a slightly widened set around POD (trivial+standard layout) types).

Using PFR you can [opt in using a macro](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/doc/html/boost_pfr/short_examples_for_the_impatient.html#:%7E:text=Define%20all%20the%20comparison%20and%20IO%20operators%20for%20my_structure%20type%20along%0A//%20with%20hash_value%20function.):

> Boost.PFR adds the following out-of-the-box functionality for
> aggregate initializable structures:
>
> - comparison functions
> - heterogeneous comparators
> - hash
> - IO streaming
> - access to members by index
> - member type retrieval
> - methods for cooperation with std::tuple
> - methods to visit each field of the structure

Example using [`BOOST_PFR_FUNCTIONS_FOR`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/doc/html/BOOST_PFR_FUNCTIONS_FOR.html):

> Defines comparison and stream operators for T along with hash_value
> function.
>
> See Also : ['Three ways of getting operators'](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/doc/html/boost_pfr/tutorial.html#boost_pfr.tutorial.three_ways_of_getting_operators) for other ways to define
> operators and more details.

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e2072e23fc668bb6)**

```
struct Point { int x, y; };

#include <boost/pfr.hpp>    
BOOST_PFR_FUNCTIONS_FOR(Point)

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
int main() {
    std::vector pv { Point{1,2}, {2,1}, {-3,4}, {1,4/2}, {-3,-4} };

    for(auto& p : pv) std::cout << p << " ";
    std::cout << "\n";

    std::set ps(begin(pv), end(pv));

    for(auto& p : ps) std::cout << p << " ";
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
{1, 2} {2, 1} {-3, 4} {1, 2} {-3, -4} 
{-3, -4} {-3, 4} {1, 2} {2, 1}
```

Using strictly [c++14](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f2d5b664a32a87b2) (specifying `vector<Point>` and `set<Point>` template arguments).

Comment: added more documentation + links

Comment: So for example  `pv[0] == pv[1]` would work like that and print false? Your example just shows standard stream output, but my question is about `operator==`. I mean you're basically saying it should work, but it would also be nice to include that in your example.

Comment: My example shows a lot more! Notice that `set` makes it ordered (`operator<`) and unique (`operator<`). But, I could have just as easily [shown a hash set](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/840207ec3729b36c) (`operator==` and `hash<Point>`). The point was me quoting the full documentation which details that indeed `pv[0] == pv[1]` works (you could also [just try that](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b6a8996f98e79005) of course)